# Carriage return in AJAX return text

Tags: javascript, php

When I run my ajax action the return text has a return character as the first char. However the echo text used to send is fixed with no spaces or returns. and if i alert the return text there is no carraige return.

I'm running the code from my Godaddy host, running MSQL with PHP5

```
innerHTML that crates the button - _("comment_"+sid).innerHTML += '<div id="reply_'+rid+'" class="reply_boxes"><div><b>Reply by you just now:</b><span id="srdb_'+rid+'"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="deleteReply(\''+rid+'\',\'reply_'+rid+'\');" title="DELETE THIS COMMENT">remove</a></span><br />'+data+'</div></div>';
                _("replyBtn_"+sid).disabled = false;
                _(ta).value = "";
```

js code -

```
function deleteComment(commentid,commentbox){
    var conf = confirm("Press OK to confirm deletion of this status and its replies");
    if(conf != true){
        return false;
    }
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/comments_system.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            var deleteOk = ajax.responseText;  //This is retuning a return carraige
            if(deleteOk = "1"){
                _(commentbox).style.display = 'none';
                _("replytext_"+commentid).style.display = 'none';
                _("replyBtn_"+commentid).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                alert(ajax.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("action=delete_comment&commentid="+commentid);
}
```

This is the PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "delete_comment"){
    if(!isset($_POST['commentid']) || $_POST['commentid'] == ""){
        mysqli_close($db_conx);
        echo "comment id is missing";
        exit();
    }
    $commentid = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['commentid']);
    // Check to make sure this logged in user actually owns that comment
    $sql = "SELECT author_name FROM comments WHERE parent_id=$commentid LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
        $author_name  = $row[author_name];
    }
    if ($author_name == $log_username) {
        mysqli_query($db_conx, "DELETE FROM comments WHERE parent_id=$commentid");
        mysqli_close($db_conx);
        echo "1";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "$sql - $author_name";
    }
}
```

So I have had to edit my code at the moment to use the int values as it would seem the IF statements still match the return value, but if i use a text return then it does not match. I have an almost identical bit of code to create the comment but this work as expected.

Comment: `if(deleteOk = "1"){`is wrong

Comment: Check the face palm things first: do you have <?php on the first line?  Is there a LF/CR stored on the database?  Use trim() on the output.

Comment: Stop using alert and start using the console API instead. There is literally nothing `alert` can do that the console can't do better, unless what you need to do is "lock the entire execution thread". If that's what you want, use alert. If you actually want to _really_ know what's in your variables, use `console.log`, `console.table`, etc.

Comment: Dharman - I'm unsure of what you're talking about, all my input data is cleaned before it is entered into the database and have both checks in both the PHP and the js before they get to the SQL for the database. Also, I'm not sure that this answers my question. However, I'm really concerned about security so I'm keen to see where im going wrong in the above code

Comment: Lawrence Cherone - The if(deleteOk = "1" this is what I'm having to do at the moment because only numeric values will = the if statement any text value does not match because I believe of the carriage return. I'm not sure what you mean by its wrong?

Comment: Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans - I'm using the console and other browser tools to ckick through the functions, this is where i see the carriage return in the data. I'm using the alert just to check also but this has no carriage return and is showing the allow i would expect to go into the if statement but it is not matching.

Comment: I’ll address a couple of your questions. 1) regarding prepared statements: this particular query looks pretty safe, but it’s a very bad habit to not use a prepared statement any time you’re injecting a value into a query. Prepared statements are The Right Way To Do It.   2) if(deleteOk=“1”) is not checking the variable; it’s assigning it.

Comment: Tim Morton - Thanks for your time, I have done a bit of research and will look into using prepared statements.  The if(deleteOk="1") is checking the line above, it was set tp if(ajax.responseText = "delete_ok") which was the echo value set from ajax but every return value from ajax is adding a prefix carriage return. The is the real question, I appreciate all the other response and advice but it still does not answer the question. I have spent 2 days on this now and even the work around i had is causing other issues now.